# Wordpress: move content of <div> automatically into custom field

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a problem that I search for in internet since hours, but cannot find any solution.

I have  `<div class ="myclass"><My Content</div>`

And I have a custom field "my_customfield".

How can I store the content of .myclass automatically in my_customfield?  It should be inserted into the database somehow I suppose. Has anybody an idea?

Comment: It is unclear what `my_customfield` is, and how it relates to a database at all.

Comment: my_customfield is the name of an empty custom_field that is created automatically when the post is published. It is empty because I would like to fill it dynamically. As decribed: with the content of a certain <div>

Comment: What does `post is published` mean?  A form submit?  An ajax request?  If there is an element on the page you are referencing with `my_customfield`, is that an id?  A class?  You're not giving us much information.  Remember, you are intimately familiar with your code base.  We are not.  You have to explain your situation to us as if we have no idea what is going on.  Because we don't

Comment: I have a form that sends information by email to WP in order to publish the content as post. The form also has a <date> field. 

I want to display the posts ASC according to the date of the <date>field. Therefore I need to store that value somewhere where i can use it for a query. A custom field might be OK. 

My functions.php creates an empty custom field after publishing the post. There I would like to insert the date. The only problem is: How  to move the date into the empty custom field.

Answer (score 0):

First Fetch the Data From myClass.

```
$html = '<div class="myclass">SomeText</div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname = "myclass";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' `$classname ')]");`
$data = $nodes{0}->nodeValue;
```

Then You Can Save $data Variable to Meta Boxes (Custom Fields).

```
add_post_meta( POST_ID, '_date', $data, true );
```

Comment: Thanks I lot, but that will not work, I suppose. <div class="myclass">SomeText</div> The Content is created dynamically. If it always were "Some Text" it would be quite easy. ;) So I do not think I can store it like that in a variable. Or can I?

Comment: In Above Code $data get the internal value of my class div. SomeText is only written for demo. It fetch the data which is present inside the div whose class is myclass.